# dealing with web application in python

Tags: python, web-applications, urllib

hello guys i'm wondering the best way to deal with web application

i  want to make python script to open http://whois.arin.net  then query ip to get information

in this case i use `urllib` but actually it'a not Interaction with it !! when i save result it's show that message `Query terms are too ambiguous. Please refine query.` or some site else show error  or access denied !

so tell me guys how to handling this problem !

Comment: Are you just sending the same queries as the browser or are you using the REST API? https://www.arin.net/resources/whoisrws/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I dunno mb some kind of unstable hack...

You can wget in following style and then grep.
eg. for ip 94.100.191.201

http://whois.arin.net/?flushCache=false&q=94.100.191.201&whoisSubmitButton=+

Comment: why? this is not what you want or didnt get the idea?